# Identifying browser tab on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

I have a nodejs web server and I need to distinguish requests from different browser tabs. Unfortunately, I cannot use different URLs for different tabs, I can only use js code. Any idea on how to identify requests to the server made from different tabs of the same browser?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to identify in which tab is opened client side. Then, send the data somehow to the server. I would even say that you can't identify the tab without using a browser specific extension.

I.E: [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) for Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Have the server generate a unique ID when the page is initially loaded into the tab.

Include that ID in each request you make back to the server from the page.